# Parse JSON replace every comma with a <br> element Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string of JSON data and I need to replace every comma with a `<br>` in javascript.

Here is my JSON `{"Items":"beans ,rice ,flour","Quantity":"4 ,5 ,6"}`

And my JSON call

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.get( url, function( data ) {

        $.each( data, function( i, val ) {

            $( "#pantry" ).append(
                '<h3>' + 
                    '<p>' +
                    items + 
                    '</p>' +
                    '<p>' +
                    val +
                    '</p>' +
                '</h3>'
            );
        });
    });
  });
```

What do I need to add as a modifier?

Answer (score 2):

You could stringify the JSON object, then use the method `replace` for Strings.

```
var test = JSON.stringify({"Items":"beans ,rice ,flour","Quantity":"4 ,5 ,6"});

var updatedTest = test.replace(/,/g, '<br>');
// Outputs:
// {"Items":"beans <br>rice <br>flour"<br>"Quantity":"4 <br>5 <br>6"}
```

This wont work corrctly though because it will update the commas that seperate each property.

This is more logical:

```
var test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({"Items":"beans ,rice ,flour","Quantity":"4 ,5 ,6"}));
var updatedTest = {};
for (prop in test){
  updatedTest[prop] = test[prop].replace(/,/g, '<br>')
}

updatedTest = JSON.stringify(updatedTest);

// updadedTest Outputs:
// {"Items":"beans <br>rice <br>flour","Quantity":"4 <br>5 <br>6"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split on `','` and join using `<br />`.

```
items.split(',').join('<br />')
```